# Adding an empty list to a dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

When I coded this:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    d[key].append([])
```

it says,

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I don't understand this error message. What is the `int` object here and how to code adding an empty list to a dictionary value?

Comment: `d[key]` returns an integer, and you call `.append` on that integer. Hence, the error

Comment: add the value of d

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about what is it that you are try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Type of value(`d[key]`) is integer, The `.append()` method does not applies on integer.

If Questions is  Append an empty list as the value if value(`d[key]`) is empty to a dictionary,

```
d = {'a':2, 'b': None, 'c':3}
for key, value in d.items():
    if not d[key]:
       d[key] = []
print(d)
```

Output: `{'a': 2, 'b': [], 'c': 3}`